# Relation between cup and cap product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, poincare-duality

I am trying to prove that a certain diagram involving cup and cap products commutes, but there is a step which I don't understand.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $R$ a commutative ring. If I fix a cochain $\phi \in C^{k}(X;R)$, I get a map
\begin{align*}
\phi  \smile (-):C^l(X;R) \longrightarrow :C^{k+l}(X;R)
\end{align*}
which sends a cochain $\psi \in C^{l}(X;R)$ to the cup product $\phi \smile \psi$.

My book now says that this map induces a map in cohomology, 
\begin{align*}
\phi  \smile (-):H^l(X;R) \longrightarrow :H^{k+l}(X;R),
\end{align*}
but I don't understand how.

I mean: if I define, for any $[\zeta] \in H^l(X;R)$, 
\begin{align*}
\phi  \smile ([\zeta]) = [\phi  \smile \zeta],
\end{align*}
nothing forces the latter to be a cocycle. So I am not even sure that this map is well defined.

Maybe this is not the correct natural definition for the cohomology map?

P.S. You may find the diagram I am talking about [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf), page 249.

Comment: Just a formatting point, using \smile for the cup product as in $a \smile b$ matches the style in Hatcher and many books, and avoids confusion with actual unions. Just personal preference though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Hatcher says "passing to homology and cohomology", I believe he implicitly means also that $\varphi$ is now assumed to be a cocycle. In that case, we do get a map in cohomology (because of the Leibniz formula, see Lemma 3.6 in page 206).

Otherwise, cupping with $\varphi$ won't induce a map in cohomology, as you pointed out. Because if one cochain is a cocycle and the other one isn't, the result will not be in general a cocycle (see the Leibniz formula again).

Comment: Indeed the cup product of two cocycles is a cocycle! My doubts though arose from the fact that I found the same discussion (without any hypoteses on the cochain $\phi$) on a couple of different references

Comment: Can you give the precise references? It seems to me that the hypothesis that $\phi$ be a cocylce is necessary. Without it, the claim already fails for $l=0$ on a space with cohomology ring with $1$. Evaluate at the $1$ and you get $d(\phi\cup 1)=\pm d\phi \cup 1=\pm d\phi\neq 0$.

Comment: I have found [this](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/kurs/mat4540h11/at2.pdf), page 68, Lemma 5.5.1.

Everything seems to work if I take $\phi$ as a cocycle, but I don't know, maybe there is something about Poincaré Duality wich I ignore.

Comment: These notes seem (at least the Poincaré Duality section) to be strongly based on Hatcher: same notation, same diagrams... My guess is therefore that the author is doing the same implicit assumption as Hatcher does in his book. This has nothing to do with Poincaré Duality, we never even mentioned manifolds in this discussion